# Is this pseudo random function any good and/or original?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

I designed this pseudo-random function algorithm that takes a `uint64` and returns a `uint64`.  I'd like to know if it is any good and if so, if it is original? If not original, who came up with it first?

First you start with 65 constant random `uint64`s.  Lets call them $P_0$ thru $P_{64}$

For an input uint64 `X` you XOR together $P_0$ and each $P_i$ where the ith bit of `X` is on.  The result of this XOR is the output `Y`.

```
uint64_t P[65];

void init() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++) P[i] = /* random number */;
}

uint64_t generate(uint64_t X) {
    uint64_t Y = P[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        if (X & (uint64_t(1) << i))
            Y ^= P[i];
    return Y;
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Depends on the context. Maybe good for a game to introduce some randomness. For cryptographic purposes you should always use a CSPRNG (cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator).

Comment: @AleksanderCH: I did develop it for for a game - but I'd be curious to know why this isn't cryptographically secure?  If you flip a bit of the input, each of the output bits flip with 50% probability.  That is the avalanche effect, no?

Comment: Cryptographically speaking, it is very bad. It is a linear function and so (for example) given a few matched input-output pairs (say 70) the function output for all possible inputs can be calculated.

Comment: @Daniel: Well you could trivially recover P by inputting (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^63).  So does that mean it isn't a one-way function?  Given some output Y how do you calculate an input X that produces that output, even if you know P?  Isn't that what is required?

Comment: You would create the binary matrix his rows are the bits of $P$; invert it and multiply  $Y$ by this inverse matrix.

Comment: It holds `generate(0)==generate(1)^generate(2)^generate(3)`, and more generally `generate(u^v^w)==generate(u)^generate(v)^generate(w)`. That is, this is affine. It is enough to disqualify the thing from a crypto standpoint.

Comment: @DanielS: When you say inverting the matrix, you mean like we're treating the elements as being in GF(2) (ie [$\mathbb{F}_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2))).  I didn't know you could invert such a matrix.  Does gauassian elimination even work over GF(2).  (I guess so, although I've never tried it.)

Comment: @fgrieu: Yeah I think I get it.  The function is trivially invertable.

Comment: Yes, [Gaussian elimination can be performed over any field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Generalizations)

Comment: Very simply speaking, if any CSPRNG, stream cipher, generic cipher or HMAC only has a key / seed size of 64 bits then the function is not considered secure; you could simply brute force the seed after all. That doesn't necessarily mean that the algorithm is insecure (RSA is secure, but RSA-512 is not), however your algorithm *requires* a 64 bit seed as input...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the question implements any one of the $2^{65\times64}\approx2^{(2^{12.02})}$ "affine" functions from $\{0,1\}^{64}$ to itself, that is functions with the property $$\forall u,v,w\in\{0,1\}^{64},\ f(u\oplus v\oplus w)=f(u)\oplus f(v)\oplus f(w)$$

That affine property makes the function useless (at least, as is) for generating cryptographic-quality pseudo-randomness. In particular, making 65 queries with chosen inputs like $0$ and $2^i$ for $i\in[0,64)$, or obtaining a little more random input/output values, is enough to fully reconstruct the function.

To put things in perspective, that well-known class of functions is a large superset of the $2^{2\times64}=2^{(2^7)}$ functions from $\{0,1\}^{64}$ to itself that can be described as a [Cyclic Redundancy Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). But it's a minuscule subclass of the $2^{(2^{64}\times64)}=2^{(2^{70})}$ functions from $\{0,1\}^{64}$ to itself.